# Hide all Dokuwiki Pagenames? (Bootstrap3 Theme)

Tags: php, css, dokuwiki

I am currently trying to hide all pagenames on my Dokuwiki. I use the bootstrap3 theme but I don't think that's too important since I believe it's similar to Doku's default theme in terms of pagename. On every page on my site: https://littlesimworld.com/ there is a pagename on the top right of the screen. I would like to hide this.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this? The wiki has permissions so you won't have access to other pages, but you can see this on the home page. This is a default setting on all Dokuwikis I believe. I want to do this because I don't feel the need for the pagename because it's just the same as the url. Mostly, I don't like how it looks and adds more clutter to the page, I am trying to create a minimalistic page!

Apologies for the rather trivial question, but I've looked everywhere on the web and can't seem to find a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution I found was to go into bootstrap3 settings from config and simply find

```
tpl»bootstrap3»showPageId
Display the DokuWiki page name (pageId) on top
```

and uncheck this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide it you can add user styles. Create (or edit if exists) conf/userstyle.css and add following lines:

```
#dokuwiki__pageheader .pageId {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Is it because you are quoting a dokuwiki pageheader, do I need to edit this somehow for bootstrap3 template? Apologies again, I am very new to this and I dont have much experience in web design.

Comment: Nope, it works. I'm not sure what happened! Thank you so much!